# Ansible playbook syntax error in task name field

Tags: ansible

Here it is:

```
- hosts: ppe32
  tasks:
  - name: update apt cache
    apt:
      update_cache=yes

  - name: make sure aide is installed and latest
    apt:
      name=aide
      state=latest

  - name: make sure fail2ban is installed and latest
    apt:
      name=fail2ban
      state=latest

  - name: make sure iptables-persistent is installed and latest
    apt:
      name=iptables-persistent
      state=latest

  - name: make sure python-pyopenssl is installed and latest
    apt:
      name=python-pyopenssl
      state=latest

  - name: generate private key
    openssl_privatekey:
      path=/etc/ssl/certs/privkey.pem
      state=present

  - name: generate csr
    openssl_csr:
      common_name={{ inventory_hostname }}
      country_name=fr
      path=/etc/ssl/certs/ansible.csr
      privatekey_path=/etc/ssl/certs/privkey.pem

  - name: generate certificate
    openssl_certificate:
      csr_path=/etc/ssl/certs/ansible.csr
      state=present
      has_expired=no
      path=/etc/ssl/certs/cert.crt
      subject={{ inventory_hostname }}

  - name: insert fail2ban conf
    template:
      src=jail.j2
      dest=/etc/fail2ban/jail.d/ssh.conf
    notify:
    - restart fail2ban

  - name: insert iptables-persistent conf
    template:
      src=iptables.j2
      dest=/etc/iptables/rules.v4
    notify:
    - restart iptables-persistent

  handlers:
  - name: restart fail2ban
    service:
      name=fail2ban
      state=restarted

  - name: restart iptables-persistent
    service:
      name=iptables-persistent
      state=restarted
```

Please keep in mind this is a work in progress, I'm just trying to solve this error when running "ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts --check":

> ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled
>   module name, or incorrect module path.
>
> The error appears to have been in '/root/web-sec.yml': line 27, column
>   5, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
>   problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> - name: generate private key
>     ^ here
>
> The error appears to have been in '/root/web-sec.yml': line 27, column
>   5, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
>   problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> - name: generate private key
>     ^ here

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Ansible do you use ?

[openssl_privatekey](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/openssl_privatekey_module.html) was introduced in Ansible 2.3
and 
[openssl_csr](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/openssl_csr_module.html) was introduced only in Ansible 2.4

Comment: That was the problem, Debian repo version is 2.2.1.0. Thanks, sorry I didn't think to check that earlier.